# Powershell functions parameters

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, microsoft-teams, powershell-cmdlet

So I created a function that assigns licenses to users. When I execute the function it shows me an error.

```
Function Create_resource_account {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [string] $UserPrincipalName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [string] $ApplicationId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
    [string] $DisplayName
)
process {
    try {
        New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -DisplayName $DisplayName
    }    
    catch {
        write-Log(“Error while creating a new application instance for a Call queue with $UserPrincipalName”)
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
        Write-Log($ErrorMessage)
        Write-Log($FailedItem)
        exit(0)
    }
}
}

Function AddLicense {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
[string] $UserPrincipalName,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
[string] $License,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
[string] $UsageLocation
)
process {
$SkuIds = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses | ForEach-Object { $_.AccountSkuId }
if ( $SkuIds -contains $License) {
    Write-Output ("No licence to assign for $UserPrincipalName")
}
else {
    try {
        Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -UsageLocation $UsageLocation 
        Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -AddLicenses $License
    }
    catch {
        write-Log(“Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to $UserPrincipalName”)
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
        Write-Log($ErrorMessage)
        Write-Log($FailedItem)
        exit(0)
    }
}
}
}
$Util2 = Get-PnPListItem -List "2"
foreach ($temp2 in $Util2) {

    $CQNom = $temp2['CQ_nom']
    $CQMail = $temp2['CQ_Compte_de_ressource']
    $CQNum = $temp2['Tel_sda']    


#Création des ressources
$newCqRa = Create_resource_account $CQMail 11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07 "RA_$CQNom"   #Call queue


#Assign licence
$User = Get-AzureADUser -objectid $newCqRa.ObjectId | select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
AddLicense $User "domain:PHONESYSTEM_VIRTUALUSER" "US"}
```

The error

```
Get-MsolUser : User Not Found.  User: CQ-JeanPierreViseur@domain.onmicrosoft.com.
Au caractère Ligne:51 : 26
+ ... nsedUser = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licen ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetUser
```

It shows me the same error for all users. I told myself that there is a problem in my function Addlicense. Someone can help me please.

Also I store what my program does in a logging file and this is what it writes to me

```
"Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to CQ-EricDesbordes@domain.onmicrosoft.com 
The parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to CQ-JeanPierreViseur@domain.onmicrosoft.com The parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."
```

Thanks to the advice of the comrades I was able to solve my problem at the addlicense function

```
Function AddLicense {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [Guid] $objectid,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]
    [String[]] $SkuidLicense,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 2)]
    [string] $UsageLocation
)
process {
    $SkuID = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectID $objectid | Select -ExpandProperty AssignedLicenses | Select SkuID
    if ( $SkuID -contains $SkuidLicense) {
        Write-Log ("No licence to assign for $newCqRa")
    }
    else {
        try {
            Set-AzureADUser -ObjectId $objectid -UsageLocation $UsageLocation
            $License = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicense
            $License.SkuId = $SkuidLicense
            $LicensesToAssign = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
            $LicensesToAssign.AddLicenses = $License
            Set-AzureADUserLicense -ObjectId $objectid -AssignedLicenses $LicensesToAssign
        }
        catch {
            write-Log(“Error while assigning PhoneSystem Virtual Licence to $newCqRa”)
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
            Write-Log($ErrorMessage)
            Write-Log($FailedItem)
            
        }
    }
}
#Attribution de la licence
AddLicense $newCqRa.ObjectId "440eaaa8-b3e0-484b-a8be-62870b9ba70a" "US"
```

Comment: Don't you need to call `Connect-MsolService` before using the `*-MsolUser` cmdlets?

Comment: Are your users using the onmicrosoft.com address as their UserPrincipalName or are they using the company email domain as their UserPrincipalName. With you saying it errors on all users, check your userprincipalname is what you expect it to be

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes I log in before running it

Comment: @JonathanWaring - Users use the onmicrosoft.com address as userPrincipalName. If I run my script without creating the AddLicense function it works normally.

Comment: `(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses` returns an array. You need to loop through to get the `AccountSkuId` for each of them and check with `-contains` instead of `-eq $License`. Also `Set-MsolUser` doesn't have a parameter `-AddLicenses`.. You need [Set-MsolUserLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0) instead

Comment: @Theo - Thank you very much for that information. Also the program says that the error is found here `$LicensedUser = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses.AccountSkuId`

Comment: Yes, that is why I commented on that error. `.licenses` is an ARRAY, so you need something like `$SkuIds = (Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName).licenses | ForEach-Object { $_.AccountSkuId }; if ($SkuIds -contains $License) {...}`

Comment: @Theo - Okay thank you. In your opinion there is no error in the parameter  userprincipalname?

Comment: No, not anymore, since now you're using `Set-MsolUserLicense` instead of `Set-MsolUser`. The latter does not have that parameter, while  `Set-MsolUserLicense` does. Whether or not a user with UserPrincipalName `CQ-JeanPierreViseur@domain.onmicrosoft.com` can be found is quite a different story.

Comment: Hello @Theo . I was able to solve my problem. Thank you so much. your advice helped me a lot